# Indexing content that is attached to some page

Tags: c#, episerver

I have this requirment to only index that data, for searching, which is being used in some page. For example if I upload a document it shouldn't be available for search until I use it in some page. I found out this code online

```
        ContentIndexer.Instance.Conventions.ForInstancesOf().ShouldIndex(x =>
        {
            var contentRepository =
                EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance();
            var contentSoftLinkRepository =
                EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance();
            var softLinks = contentSoftLinkRepository.Load(x.ContentLink, true);

            try
            {
                foreach (var softLink in softLinks)
                {

                    if (softLink.SoftLinkType == ReferenceType.ExternalReference ||
                        softLink.SoftLinkType == ReferenceType.ImageReference)
                    {
                        var content =
                            contentRepository.Get(softLink.OwnerContentLink);
                        if (!ContentIndexer.Instance.Conventions.ShouldIndexConvention.ShouldIndex(content).Value) // don't index referenced file if content is marked as not indexed
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // only index if content is published
                        var publicationStatus =
                            content.PublishedInLanguage()[softLink.OwnerLanguage.Name];

                        if (publicationStatus != null &&
                            (publicationStatus.StartPublish == null ||
                             publicationStatus.StartPublish < DateTime.Now) &&
                            (publicationStatus.StopPublish == null ||
                             DateTime.Now < publicationStatus.StopPublish))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // ooops something went wrong. Better not index this one ;-)
            }

            return false;
        });
```

This works when I attach softlinks. But lets say a page has a property called Content type and when I add something in there, lets say a block which has softlinks to that document, it doesn't work. I am stuck in there. Any hints?

Comment: Looks like code you provided has lost all angle brackets like `<IContentSoftLinkRepository>` etc

Comment: As for question - no magic here, I think you will need to manually process every `SoftLink` instance, check owner, if it is block - find all places where it is used etc. So technically soft link shows use "direct usage", and what you need is to calculate "indirect usage" by traversing links (keeping in mind there can be and should be cycles in such journey etc)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a wildcard * host configured on any of your sites?

Check Admin > Manage websites and go through all sites to see if there is a * configured. 
[image]

Having a wildcard tells Episerver Find to index standalone content (i.e. globalassets) using the site primary URL that contains the wildcard, regardless of it being referenced. If you don't have a wildcard configured, Episerver Find can't index content that are NOT referenced (i.e. globalassets) because it cannot generate a public URL for it. Global assets that are referenced will be indexed using the domain of the site that references it. Hope this helps.